# manage setinterval & clearInterval methods in titanium studio

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile

In my android app, developing by titanium studio 3.1.3, I have tab group where in the last(fifth tab) I am using button to open a new page
-> new page contains switch, if switch is on I am calling a method like

```
function locationSetEnable() {
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('getLocation', 'YES');
    getlocation_coords();
    timer = setInterval(getlocation_coords, 20000);
}
```

so it is calling getlocation_coords method in every 20 seconds, and If switch is off I am calling other method,

```
function locationSetDisable() {
    Titanium.Geolocation.removeEventListener('location', locationCallback);
    clearInterval(timer);
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('getLocation', 'NO');
}
```

so, here clear interval is working properly the method getlocation_coords calling is stopped.

it is happening only I am on the same screen.

My issue is :

If my switch is on, and I moved into any other screen/tab and coming back to same screen and now I am going off my switch this time the clearInterval is not working, it is calling autometically the getlocation_coords method is calling continiously, how do I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to make your "timer" variable global. Like you can create `var timer = null;` only once in app.js. Now you can access it in all .js files.

Comment: thanks for response.  I tried it, but it is not working, behaving same

Comment: It did worked for me. Sorry if it didn't worked for you.